# Is there a better way to define the time range in this query?

Tags: mysql

We have a table here called as `attendance_log` which captures the login & logout time and I'm working with a query to obtain and calculate the working hours accurately. The query that I come up with actually works very well however I'm wondering if there's a way to shorten some section. Below are the base of my query:

My employer is still using MySQL 4.1 (unfortunately) so ..

```
SELECT staffid,DATE(CHECKINOUT) AS dci,
       MIN(TIME(CHECKINOUT)) atin,
       CASE WHEN MIN(TIME(CHECKINOUT)) <= '08:30:59' THEN '08:30:00'
       WHEN MIN(TIME(CHECKINOUT)) BETWEEN '08:31:00' AND '09:00:59' THEN '09:00:00'
       WHEN MIN(TIME(CHECKINOUT)) BETWEEN '09:01:00' AND '09:30:59' THEN '09:30:00'
       WHEN MIN(TIME(CHECKINOUT)) BETWEEN '09:31:00' AND '10:00:59' THEN '10:00:00'
       WHEN MIN(TIME(CHECKINOUT)) BETWEEN '10:01:00' AND '10:30:59' THEN '10:30:00'
       WHEN MIN(TIME(CHECKINOUT)) BETWEEN '10:31:00' AND '11:00:59' THEN '11:00:00'
       WHEN MIN(TIME(CHECKINOUT)) BETWEEN '11:01:00' AND '11:30:59' THEN '11:30:00'
       WHEN MIN(TIME(CHECKINOUT)) BETWEEN '11:31:00' AND '12:00:59' THEN '12:00:00'
       WHEN MIN(TIME(CHECKINOUT)) BETWEEN '12:01:00' AND '12:30:59' THEN '12:30:00'
       WHEN MIN(TIME(CHECKINOUT)) BETWEEN '12:31:00' AND '13:00:59' THEN '13:00:00'
       END AS Time_IN,
       MAX(TIME(CHECKINOUT)) AS atout,
       CASE 
       WHEN MAX(TIME(CHECKINOUT)) <= '08:59:59' THEN '08:30:00' 
       WHEN MAX(TIME(CHECKINOUT)) <= '09:29:59' THEN '09:00:00' 
       WHEN MAX(TIME(CHECKINOUT)) <= '09:59:59' THEN '09:30:00' 
       WHEN MAX(TIME(CHECKINOUT)) <= '10:29:59' THEN '10:00:00' 
       WHEN MAX(TIME(CHECKINOUT)) <= '10:59:59' THEN '10:30:00' 
       WHEN MAX(TIME(CHECKINOUT)) <= '11:29:59' THEN '11:00:00' 
       WHEN MAX(TIME(CHECKINOUT)) <= '11:59:59' THEN '11:30:00' 
       WHEN MAX(TIME(CHECKINOUT)) <= '12:29:59' THEN '12:00:00'
       ELSE MAX(TIME(CHECKINOUT)) 
       END AS Time_OUT,
       DAYNAME(CHECKINOUT) AS dname,
       GROUP_CONCAT(TIME(checkinout) ORDER BY TIME(checkinout) SEPARATOR ' ') allci,COUNT(*) cnt
  FROM attendance_log, 
       (SELECT @nday:=28800, @hday:=16200, @rtime:=3600) v
 WHERE staffid='HS078' 
   AND MONTH(checkinout)=MONTH(CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
   AND YEAR(checkinout)=YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY DATE(CHECKINOUT);
```

As you can see, there's too much going on in the `CASE` expression to obtain both `Time_IN` and `Time_OUT` value. I recently discovered more about using variables in MySQL but for now I'm using it for other function, not in this query though.

I've prepared a fiddle here and the query is much longer than the example I gave above = http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0230f/3

So my question is, how can I shorten the condition in `CASE` expression? Maybe I define first "valid time in" value and from there run an interval for every 30 minutes like that?

**Edit:**

I manage to shorten my query by 'artificially' creating the minutes and seconds while adding 1 hour the login hour and retaining the logout hour extracted from the record;

```
SELECT staffid,
       DATE(CHECKINOUT) AS dci,
       DAYNAME(CHECKINOUT) AS dname,      
       MIN(TIME(CHECKINOUT)) atin,      
       CASE WHEN MIN(TIME(checkinout)) < '08:30:59' THEN '08:30:00' 
       WHEN MIN(TIME(checkinout)) > '08:30:59' THEN 
       CONCAT_WS(':',CASE WHEN MINUTE(MIN(TIME(checkinout))) > 30 THEN LPAD(HOUR(MIN(checkinout))+1,2,'0') 
       WHEN MINUTE(MIN(TIME(checkinout))) <= 30 THEN LPAD(HOUR(MIN(checkinout)),2,'0')END,
       CASE WHEN MINUTE(MIN(TIME(checkinout))) > 30 THEN '00' 
       WHEN MINUTE(MIN(TIME(checkinout))) <= 30 THEN 30 END,'00') END tin,       
       MAX(TIME(CHECKINOUT)) AS atout,      
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*)=4 AND MAX(TIME(checkinout)) < '18:00:00' THEN '17:30:00' 
       WHEN COUNT(*)=2 AND DAYNAME(checkinout)='Saturday' AND MAX(TIME(checkinout)) > '13:00:00' THEN '13:00:00'
       WHEN COUNT(*) IN (0,1,3) THEN 'Incomplete'
       ELSE CONCAT_WS(':',LPAD(HOUR(MAX(checkinout)),2,'0'),CASE WHEN MINUTE(MAX(TIME(checkinout))) < 30 THEN '00'
       WHEN MINUTE(MAX(TIME(checkinout))) >= 30 THEN 30 END,'00') END tout,
       GROUP_CONCAT(TIME(checkinout) ORDER BY TIME(checkinout) SEPARATOR ' ') allci,COUNT(*) cnt
  FROM attendance_log, (SELECT @nday:=28800, @hday:=16200, @rtime:=3600) v
 WHERE staffid='HS078' 
   AND MONTH(checkinout)=MONTH(CURDATE()) 
   AND YEAR(checkinout)=YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY DATE(CHECKINOUT);
```

The idea is very simple, regardless if a staff login before 8:30 a.m, the query will capture 8:30 a.m. Once they exceed a minute from that will be considered as 30 minutes late. However, if logout time suppose to be at 05:30 p.m., it needs to have the exact 30 minutes interval to be captured as overtime. So for example:

1. login at 8:31 a.m resulted as 9:00 a.m.
2. login at 9:01 a.m resulted as 9:30 a.m.
3. logout at 5:45 p.m resulted as 5:30 p.m.
4. logout at 6:15 p.m resulted as 6:00 p.m.

Extra:

1. 1 hour of rest time is allocated for each day and it can be anytime from 12:00 p.m to 2:00 p.m. For example, a staff can go to rest at 12:15 p.m but had to come back at (or before) 1:15 p.m. If a staff take 30 mins or less  to rest, the remaining 30 mins is considered as replacement time for any lateness occurred before current date.
2. Every two weeks, a staff will have one full day (8:30 a.m-5:30 p.m) shift & one half day (8:30 a.m-1:00p.m) shift.

Comment: You can change all the `BETWEEN x AND y` to just `<= y` since the cases are in order by time.

Comment: But it looks like what you really want to do is round the times up to the next multiple of 30 minutes. Convert the time to a number of seconds since midnight, then use `1800 * (CEIL(seconds / 1800))` to round it up, then convert that back to a time.

Comment: Silly me @Barmar .. I should've figure that one out (`<=`) when I do the condition below. I'll try your suggestion

Comment: @tcadidot0 check if your MySQL Version supports [`Time_format()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format)  or  [`Date_format()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) functions. You can try with them as well, with little math.

Comment: It does @MadhurBhaiya , I'm actually trying the time_format() function now.. The suggestion from Barmar somehow triggered an idea in me. Thanks for the link! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some testing with @Barmar suggestion, I figured that his way is much shorter than anything I've tried:

```
SELECT *, SEC_TO_TIME(tin), SEC_TO_TIME(atout), SEC_TO_TIME(ctout) FROM
(SELECT A.*,
      CASE WHEN MIN(timechk) <= @chkin THEN @chkin 
      ELSE CEIL(MIN(timechk)/1800)*1800 END AS tin, -- here I used @Barmar suggestion,
      MAX(timechk) atout,
      FLOOR(MAX(timechk)/1800)*1800 ctout,
      COUNT(*) AS cnt,
      GROUP_CONCAT(timechk ORDER BY timechk SEPARATOR ' ') timelist FROM
(SELECT staffid,DATE(CHECKINOUT) AS dci,checkinout,
       DAYNAME(CHECKINOUT) AS dname,
       TIME_TO_SEC(checkinout) AS timechk
  FROM attendance_log
 WHERE staffid='HS078' 
   AND MONTH(checkinout)=MONTH('2019-06-03') 
   AND YEAR(checkinout)=YEAR('2019-06-03')) A CROSS JOIN
(SELECT @nday:=28800,@hday:=16200,@anhour:=3600,@chkin:=30600,@chkout:=63000,@min30:=1800) v
GROUP BY dci) V;
```

Of course there are still many operations that I had to do manually but as far as the base query goes and compared to my earlier query attempts, this satisfy my needs at the moment.